# Entity Framework Code First: One-to-Many relation (empty list)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a WCF project and I generate the database with Entity framework v6 and code-first.
But I have a problem with the relation between the class User and FeedRss. I want several FeedRss for each User. My code work (no exception) but don't add in the ICollection feeds (in user), this list is empty after the recovery in the database.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    ...
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<FeedRSS> feeds { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        feeds = new List<FeedRSS>();
    }
}
```

one user->many feedRss

```
public class FeedRSS
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public FeedRSS()
    {
    }
 }
```

> ```
> public class UsersContext : DbContext
> {
>     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
>     public DbSet<FeedRSS> Feeds { get; set; }
> }
> ```

My function for test my code (but return a empty list) :

```
    public User getUser(int Id)
    {
        using (UsersContext context = new UsersContext())
        {
            return context.Users.ToList().Find(
                    delegate(User u) {
                        return u.UserID == Id;
                    });
        }
    }

    public List<FeedRSS> getFeedListTest(User u)
    {
        using (UsersContext ctx = new UsersContext())
        {
            User user = ctx.Users.First(i => i.UserID == u.UserID);
            FeedRSS f = new FeedRSS() { name = "code", link = "uri" };
            user.feeds.Add(f);
            //the list user.feeds lenght is = 1
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            //update working
        }
        //get the same user in the database but the list uuu.feeds lenght is 0 :(
        User uuu = this.getUser(u.UserID);
        return uuu.feeds.ToList();
     }
```

I tested other code very different (fluent API, force the UserId in FeedRss..) but I do not understand the principle of the relation in entity framework... I tried unsuccessfully several examples code...

*And sorry for my approximate English

Comment: Can you add the code of getUser method ?
I think you must add an Include(p => p.feeds) to your query.

Comment: Done, I didn't know include. I rtfm ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either load feeds with `Include(...)` statement as CodeNotFound suggested or you can make the `feeds` collection virtual - that will enable lazy loading and EF will load feeds for you automatically on the fly.

```
public class User {
    ...

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<FeedRSS> feeds { get; set; }
}
```

You can find a nice article about lazy loading and eager loading on the [MSDN portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232)

Comment: Dang `virtual`! I keep forgetting it!